# Not able to port forward from local to redis server in wrokload in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, google-kubernetes-engine, portforwarding

I am trying to connect to redis cache in dev server which is a pod in GCP. we are trying to connect it through a proxy server using below command

```
gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "<zone>" "proxy-server" --project "project-name" --internal-ip --ssh-flag="-NL <local_port>:<redis-server-ip>:<port>"
```

but its throwing error in google cloud console installed in my windows system
error is **'unknown option "-NL"'**

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.beta.ssh) [C:\Users\<user-dir>\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\sdk\putty.exe] exited with return code [1].
```

but its running fine in mac, please help me in resolving the issue at the earliest.

As suggested by one of the answer, tried running below command

```
kubectl port-forward pod/pod-58759-s4wfz 6377:6379
```

getting this error now:

```
C:\Windows\system32>kubectl port-forward pod/pod-587597c46d-s4wfz 6377:6379
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:6377 -> 6379
Forwarding from [::1]:6377 -> 6379
Handling connection for 6377
E0120 12:34:32.504209   18476 portforward.go:406] an error occurred forwarding 6377 -> 6379: error forwarding port 6379 to pod a5bba767d7ec94aaf, uid : exit status 1: 2022/01/20 07:04:34 socat[910] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:6379, 16): Connection refused
E0120 12:34:32.508193   18476 portforward.go:234] lost connection to pod
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 1 day of effort I found an answer which corrected my command, just need to use below command, in place of -NL we should use -N -L in windows

```
gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "<zone>" "proxy-server" --project "project-name" --internal-ip -- -N -L <local_port>:<redis-server-ip>:<port>
```

Answer (score 1):

Putty SSH (and the OpenSSH client for windows as well) does not support the `-N` flag.  But

```
gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "<zone>" "proxy-server" --project "project-name" --internal-ip --ssh-flag="-L <local_port>:<redis-server-ip>:<port>"
```

should work just fine on Windows.

Comment: it would open a new putty terminal for the proxy server but we need to connect using local  host : port, so that i can config it in code as well

Answer (score 1):

If your redis server is deployed on GKE, you can use kubectl port-forward. It should look like

`kubectl port-forward pod/POD_NAME local-port:redis-server-port`

And use localhost:local-port to connect to your redis server

This should work regardless of the OS

Comment: getting below error:
C:\Windows\system32>kubectl port-forward pod/pod-587597c46d-s4wfz 6377:6379
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:6377 -> 6379
Forwarding from [::1]:6377 -> 6379
Handling connection for 6377
E0120 12:34:32.504209   18476 portforward.go:406] an error occurred forwarding 6377 -> 6379: error forwarding port 6379 to pod a5bba767d7ec94aaf, uid : exit status 1: 2022/01/20 07:04:34 socat[910] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:6379, 16): Connection refused
E0120 12:34:32.508193   18476 portforward.go:234] lost connection to pod

Comment: Can you try with --address 0.0.0.0. Something like ```kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 pod/pod_name 6379:6379

Comment: I still getting same error:
C:\Windows\system32>kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 deployment/<name> 6377:6379
Forwarding from 0.0.0.0:6377 -> 6379
Handling connection for 6377
E0120 17:23:40.252812   15800 portforward.go:406] an error occurred forwarding 6377 -> 6379: error forwarding port 6379 to pod 7450e6254c, uid : exit status 1: 2022/01/20 11:53:40 socat[480] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:6379, 16): Connection refused
E0120 17:23:40.257023   15800 portforward.go:234] lost connection to pod